# Execute static method in @NamedQuery-head

Tags: java, hibernate, static-methods, named-query

I want to execute a static method in the `@NamedQuery` of a class. Like this:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "allFailures", query = "select failureInfo from FailureInfo failureInfo where failureInfo.counter <="+ CountClass.myMethod() + "AND failureInfo.counter <> 0 order by failureInfo.counter asc LIMIT 1")
```

As you can see, i wanna call the "CountClass.myMethod()"-Method.
But I only can choose from variables. My method doesn't show up as an option. Is there a way to call my method in the @NamedQuery?

The Method is static and I can call it within the class. But as I said, not in the @NamedQuery.

Comment: I think that named query should be constant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, you want to parametrize the query. You can use regular parameters with named queries like this:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "allFailures", query = "select failureInfo from FailureInfo
                                  failureInfo where failureInfo.counter <= :counter 
                                  AND failureInfo.counter <> 0 
                                  order by failureInfo.counter asc LIMIT 1")
```

Once you have constructed the query, set the parameter, using a static method a regular method or a variable:

```
TypedQuery<FailureInfo> query =
      em.createNamedQuery("FailureInfo.allFailures", FailureInfo.class);
query.setParameter("counter", MyClass.myMethod());
query.getResultList();
```

Comment: First, thx for your Answer. And where do I have to write this method in the class?

Comment: @kostja I've seen it. Do I have to write a method inside my class where the NamedQuery is? Or somewhere else?

Comment: You can write both methods - the one creating the query as well as the one generating the parameter value - in any class of your choosing. Importing the entity class gives you access to the query definition.

Comment: So I dont have to call this method? I only have to write it in my class where the NamedQuery is?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand. The method `MyClass.myMethod()` will be called whenever the query is evaluated, this happens inside the `query.setParameter(...)` call.